Why do I get error when importing Python module in Databricks?
I'm trying to import a module using Python files in Databricks, but it's not a notebook and not Spark. Python version 3.10.12.
In the Databricks workspace (Git repo, not user workspace), I define this in testmodule.py:
def sum_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = 'black'

    def calculate_area(self):
        return round(math.pi * self.radius ** 2, 2)

In another Python file, I run
import testmodule as tm
tm.sum_numbers(4,20)

which correctly gives the output of 24. So why can't I do this?
from testmodule import Circle

ImportError: cannot import name 'Circle' from 'testmodule' (/Workspace/Repos/myuserID@mycompany.com/myGitRepo/testmodule.py)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-123>, line 12
     11 tm.sum_numbers(4,20)
---> 12 from testmodule import Circle

FYI, I'm aware how to import a notebook like this, but I need to be able to run the code in other environments that may not be Databricks or Spark.
%run ./testmodule


Are you adding to testmodule.py as you go? You may need to reload the module after making changes to testmodule.py (and saving). You can detach/reattach the cluster and re-run, use dbutils.library.restartPython() or importlib reload.

This code should work as shown here.  So, there must be some difference between this code and your actual code.

@s_pike yes I re-ran testmodule.py so it's updated

@JohnGordon I believe this is particular to Databricks. If you don't know Databricks, then don't suggest I misrepresented the issue.

@s_pike ah yes, I had to detach/reattach the script that I'm running. I see that just running testmodule.py was not enough. Thank you.

@Chuck, yes, that's correct. Running testmoduly.py doesn't do anything for your notebook - the notebook environment is (should be) isolated on the cluster. Glad reloading solved your issue.

@Chuck I did not suggest any kind of misrepresentation.  You said you had to detach/reattach the script, so yes in fact this was not the actual code being executed, which is exactly what I said.
